# Antiforgery token in Vuejs SPA

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I used a security scan library in my .NET 6 proyect (Is only backend, not mvc) and the front is in Vuejs SPA and I had the next warning:

```
Controller method is potentially vulnerable to Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF).
```

Reading abuot that, I found that I have to use [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] in my controller. For example:

```
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload([FromForm] FormModel model)
```

The problem is that I only found examples with asp.net MVC, not with SPA frontend, so my question is. Is neccessary to add this antiforgerytoken if the frontend is not asp.net MVC? And if it is correct, how can I do this?